# Vue 3 Breadcrumb did not work with <Script setup>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, pinia

I need your help for my Breadcrumb component.
It did work last time but after I add the Pinia it did not work anymore.
I don't know if this is related to Pinia or not.

This is the screenshot of the project

[my_vue_project_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1lco.png)

If you additional detail more than below, please let me know

Thank you all in advance

Also, I'm not sure my Vue project structure is correct or not.

```
Main layout
|
|- BreadCrumb
|- RouterView
```

I put BreadCrumb component inside every View pages. Like this (for example)

```
<script setup>
import breadcrumb from '../../components/breadcrumb.vue';

  const pages=[{ name: 'ช่าง', href: '/staff', current: true }]
  const technicians = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Mr A', score: 25, role: 'กลึง' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Mr B', score: 35, role: 'เจาะ' },
  ]
</script>

<template>
      <breadcrumb :pages="pages"/>
  <div class="space-y-6 pt-8 sm:space-y-5 sm:pt-10">
    <div class="sm:flex sm:items-center">
      <div class="sm:flex-auto">
        <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900">รายชื่อช่าง</h1>
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-700">Admin</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-16 sm:flex-none">
        <router-link to="/staff/add">
          <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent 
          bg-indigo-600 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 
          focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:w-auto">เพิ่มช่าง</button>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-8 flex flex-col">
      <div class="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
        <div class="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle md:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div class="overflow-hidden shadow ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 md:rounded-lg">
            <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
              <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">ชื่อ</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">แผนก</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">คะแนน</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-6">
                    <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
                <tr v-for="technician in technicians" :key="technician.id">
                  <td class="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">{{ technician.name }}</td>
                  <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ technician.role }}</td>
                  <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ technician.score }}</td>
                  <td class="relative whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'editstaff', params: { id: technician.id }}" 
                      class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"
                      >Edit<span class="sr-only">, {{ technician.name }}</span>
                    </router-link>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my BreadCrumb.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ChevronRightIcon, HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/20/solid'

</script>
<template>
    <nav class="flex" aria-label="Breadcrumb">
        <ol role="list" class="flex items-center space-x-4">
        <li>
            <div>
            <a href="/" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                <HomeIcon class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0" aria-hidden="true" />
                <span class="sr-only">Home</span>
            </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li v-for="page in pages" :key="page.name">
            <div class="flex items-center">
            <ChevronRightIcon class="h-5 w-5 flex-shrink-0 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
            <a :href="page.href" class="ml-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700" 
            :aria-current="page.current ? 'page' : undefined">{{ page.name }}</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ol>
    </nav> 
</template>
```

Lastly, this is my main Layout (Not sure if this is related too or not

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { Dialog, DialogPanel, TransitionChild, TransitionRoot } from '@headlessui/vue'
import {
  HomeIcon,
  Bars3Icon,
  FolderIcon,
  UsersIcon,
  XMarkIcon
} from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'

const authenticated = false;

const navigation = [
  { name: 'home', to: '/', icon: HomeIcon },
  { name: 'enj', to: '/staff', icon: UsersIcon },
  { name: 'proj', to: '/project', icon: FolderIcon },
  { name: 'selectproj', to: '/selectproject', icon: FolderIcon },
  { name: 'validateproj', to: '/validateproject', icon: FolderIcon },
]
const sidebarOpen = ref(false)

</script>
<template>
    <div>
      <TransitionRoot as="template" :show="sidebarOpen">
        <Dialog as="div" class="relative z-40 md:hidden" @close="sidebarOpen = false">
          <TransitionChild as="template" enter="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0" enter-to="opacity-100" leave="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300" leave-from="opacity-100" leave-to="opacity-0">
            <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-75" />
          </TransitionChild>
  
          <div class="fixed inset-0 z-40 flex">
            <TransitionChild as="template" enter="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform" enter-from="-translate-x-full" enter-to="translate-x-0" leave="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform" leave-from="translate-x-0" leave-to="-translate-x-full">
              <DialogPanel class="relative flex w-full max-w-xs flex-1 flex-col bg-gray-800">
                <TransitionChild as="template" enter="ease-in-out duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0" enter-to="opacity-100" leave="ease-in-out duration-300" leave-from="opacity-100" leave-to="opacity-0">
                  <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 -mr-12 pt-2">
                    <button type="button" class="ml-1 flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white" @click="sidebarOpen = false">
                      <span class="sr-only">Close sidebar</span>
                      <XMarkIcon class="h-6 w-6 text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </TransitionChild>
                <div class="h-0 flex-1 overflow-y-auto pt-5 pb-4">
                  <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center px-4">
                    <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500" alt="Your Company" />
                  </div>
                  <nav class="mt-5 space-y-1 px-2">
                    <router-link v-for="item in navigation" :key="item.name" :to="item.to" class="['text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white', 'group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium rounded-md']">
                      <component :is="item.icon" :class="[isActive ? 'text-gray-300' : 'text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300', 'mr-4 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6']" aria-hidden="true" />
                      {{ item.name }}
                    </router-link>
                  </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 bg-gray-700 p-4">
                  <a href="#" class="group block flex-shrink-0">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                      <div>
                        <img class="inline-block h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="ml-3">
                        <p class="text-base font-medium text-white">Tom Cook</p>
                        <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300">View profile</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </DialogPanel>
            </TransitionChild>
            <div class="w-14 flex-shrink-0">
              <!-- Force sidebar to shrink to fit close icon -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </TransitionRoot>
  
      <!-- Static sidebar for desktop -->
      <div class="hidden md:fixed md:inset-y-0 md:flex md:w-64 md:flex-col">
        <!-- Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like -->
        <div class="flex min-h-0 flex-1 flex-col bg-gray-800">
          <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col overflow-y-auto pt-5 pb-4">
            <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center px-4">
              <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500" alt="Your Company" />
            </div>
            <nav class="mt-5 flex-1 space-y-1 px-2">
              <RouterLink v-for="item in navigation" :key="item.name" :to="item.to" :class="[item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white', 'group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md']">
                <component :is="item.icon" :class="[item.current ? 'text-gray-300' : 'text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300', 'mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6']" aria-hidden="true" />
                {{ item.name }}
              </RouterLink>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 bg-gray-700 p-4">
            <div class="group block w-full flex-shrink-0">
              <div v-if="authenticated" class="flex items-center">
                <div class="ml-3">
                  <p class="text-base font-medium text-white pl-2">:Username</p>
                  <RouterLink to="/">
                  <p class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-200">Logout</p>
                  </RouterLink>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div v-else class="flex items-center">
                <div class="ml-3">
                <RouterLink to="/signin">
                  <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-200">เข้าสู่ระบบ</p>
                  </RouterLink>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col md:pl-64">
        <div class="sticky top-0 z-10 bg-gray-100 pl-1 pt-1 sm:pl-3 sm:pt-3 md:hidden">
          <button type="button" class="-ml-0.5 -mt-0.5 inline-flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-md text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500" @click="sidebarOpen = true">
            <span class="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
            <Bars3Icon class="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <main class="flex-1">
          <div class="py-6">
            <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
              <!-- Replace with your content -->
              <slot>
                <RouterView/>
              </slot>
              <!-- /End replace -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Comment: You are using a `pages` variable in your `Breadcrumb.vue` component, but you haven't declared the `props` for the component to accept it as input.

Comment: I tried add 
`const props = defineProps(['pages'])`
But this is not working.

I'm not sure if this is correct or not

Comment: saying there's an unknown problem and posting all your code is like asking others to find a needle in a haystack.  please do _some_ debugging on your own to try and narrow the problem down.  try adding console.logs to verify values and/or use [vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) to verify the live state of your components.